# How to resize media partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, boot-partition

When installing Xubuntu, I ended up with a media partition that was 120GB and a home partition that was 20GB.
[Gparted display of partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dknKo.png)

Is there any way for me to move some of the storage from the massive media partition to the Home drive? or am I stuck with wasted space unless I do a full reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not a LVM partition and it's an ext4 partition it should be easily applicable, but probably you need to do this from a LiveCD since you need to unmount the /dev/sda3 partition.

You can resize and move the partition with right clicking on a partition and selecting Resize/Move option. But there is a possibility that you may encounter data loss which is probably going to be emphasized by Gparted so make a backup before doing this.

[GParted Resize Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufO0t.png)